# Why is my button rendering another button?

Tags: java, button, graphics, hover, paintcomponent

i'm facing a graphic paint problem that I don't know what is happening.

Here's the problem:

I have 2 buttons:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmQcw.png]

1. Each button have it's own class.
2. Each class have it's own hover effect.
3. I'm using TimingFramework library to make the hover effect

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejdSP.png]

4. I'm using easing functions in hover event, each button use this class.

Left button hover:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODAOn.png]

Right button hover:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2e8F.png]

Whenever I hover the left button and fast change to the right button (before hover ends), the right button becomes this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HadcF.png]

I can see that the right button renders the left button graphic, but I don't know why, I've tried to override each paintComponent method but nothing seems to work, if anybody can help me, please, help me.

The codes that I used to:

> Right button: Label_Round.java

```
package com.sm.component;
import com.sm.easings.EasingsFunctions;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.Animator;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTarget;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTargetAdapter;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.interpolation.Interpolator;

public class Label_Round extends JLabel {

private ImageIcon selectedIcon;
private ImageIcon lblIcon;
private Color LR_colorCircleAroundBackground = new Color(255, 255, 255);
private boolean LR_circleAroundBackground = false;
private boolean LR_fitIcon = true;
private boolean LR_hoverEffect = false;
private int LR_fitIconSizeDiff = 10;
private Color LR_background = new Color(255, 255, 255);
private Color LR_backgroundHover = new Color(255, 255, 255);

// Animation
Animator animatorInBackground;
Animator animatorOutBackground;

public Label_Round() {
    super.setOpaque(false);
    super.setFocusable(false);
    super.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    initAnimations();
    initEvents();
}

private void initEvents() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (LR_hoverEffect) {
                if (animatorInBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorInBackground.stop();
                }
                if (animatorOutBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorOutBackground.stop();
                }
                animatorInBackground.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (LR_hoverEffect) {
                if (animatorInBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorInBackground.stop();
                }
                if (animatorOutBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorOutBackground.stop();
                }
                animatorOutBackground.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initAnimations() {
    TimingTarget targetBackground = new TimingTargetAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void timingEvent(float fraction) {
            if (animatorInBackground.isRunning()) {
                int rgbColor1 [] = new int [] {getBackground().getRed(), getBackground().getGreen(), getBackground().getBlue()};
                int rgbColor2 [] = new int [] {getLR_backgroundHover().getRed(), getLR_backgroundHover().getGreen(), getLR_backgroundHover().getBlue()};
                int rgbFinal [] = new int [3];
                boolean factorCalculos [] = new boolean [3]; // True = Resta - False = Suma
                for (int i = 0; i < rgbFinal.length; i++) {
                    if (rgbColor1 [i] > rgbColor2 [i]) {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] - ((rgbColor1 [i] - rgbColor2 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = true;
                    } else {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] + ((rgbColor2 [i] - rgbColor1 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = false;
                    }
                }
                Color finalColor = new Color(rgbFinal [0], rgbFinal [1], rgbFinal [2]);
                setBackground(finalColor);
                if (getLR_backgroundHover().equals(finalColor)) {
                    animatorInBackground.stop();
                }
            } else if (animatorOutBackground.isRunning()) {
                int rgbColor1 [] = new int [] {getBackground().getRed(), getBackground().getGreen(), getBackground().getBlue()};
                int rgbColor2 [] = new int [] {getLR_background().getRed(), getLR_background().getGreen(), getLR_background().getBlue()};
                int rgbFinal [] = new int [3];
                boolean factorCalculos [] = new boolean [3]; // True = Resta - False = Suma
                for (int i = 0; i < rgbFinal.length; i++) {
                    if (rgbColor1 [i] > rgbColor2 [i]) {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] - ((rgbColor1 [i] - rgbColor2 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = true;
                    } else {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] + ((rgbColor2 [i] - rgbColor1 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = false;
                    }
                }
                Color finalColor = new Color(rgbFinal [0], rgbFinal [1], rgbFinal [2]);
                setBackground(finalColor);
                if (getLR_background().equals(finalColor)) {
                    animatorOutBackground.stop();
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    };
    animatorInBackground = new Animator(500, targetBackground);
    animatorInBackground.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
        @Override
        public float interpolate(float f) {
            return EasingsFunctions.easeInOutSine(f);
        }
    });
    animatorOutBackground = new Animator(500, targetBackground);
    animatorOutBackground.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
        @Override
        public float interpolate(float f) {
            return EasingsFunctions.easeInOutSine(f);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setColor(getBackground());
    if (LR_circleAroundBackground) {
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    } else {
        g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    // Icon
    if (selectedIcon != null) {
        if (LR_fitIcon) {
            lblIcon = new ImageIcon(((ImageIcon) selectedIcon).getImage().getScaledInstance(getWidth() - LR_fitIconSizeDiff, getHeight() - LR_fitIconSizeDiff, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
        } else {
            lblIcon = (ImageIcon) selectedIcon;
        }
        g2d.drawImage(lblIcon.getImage(), ((getWidth() / 2) - (lblIcon.getIconWidth() / 2)), ((getHeight()/ 2) - (lblIcon.getIconHeight()/ 2)), this);
    }
}

// Para no dejar que el usuario diseñe el botón
@Override
public void setBackground(Color bg) {
    super.setBackground(bg);
}

@Override
public Color getBackground() {
    return super.getBackground();
}

@Override
public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    super.setCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
    super.setIcon(icon);
    selectedIcon = (ImageIcon) icon;
}

@Override
public Icon getIcon() {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setOpaque(boolean isOpaque) {
    super.setOpaque(false);
}

@Override
public void setFocusable(boolean focusable) {
    super.setFocusable(false);
}

@Override
public void setHorizontalTextPosition(int textPosition) {
    super.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment) {
    super.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setVerticalAlignment(int alignment) {
    super.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setVerticalTextPosition(int textPosition) {
    super.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setBorder(Border border) {
    super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

public Color getLR_colorCircleAroundBackground() {
    return LR_colorCircleAroundBackground;
}

public void setLR_colorCircleAroundBackground(Color LR_colorCircleAroundBackground) {
    this.LR_colorCircleAroundBackground = LR_colorCircleAroundBackground;
}

public boolean isLR_circleAroundBackground() {
    return LR_circleAroundBackground;
}

public void setLR_circleAroundBackground(boolean LR_circleAroundBackground) {
    this.LR_circleAroundBackground = LR_circleAroundBackground;
}

public boolean isLR_fitIcon() {
    return LR_fitIcon;
}

public void setLR_fitIcon(boolean LR_fitIcon) {
    this.LR_fitIcon = LR_fitIcon;
}

public int getLR_fitIconSizeDiff() {
    return LR_fitIconSizeDiff;
}

public void setLR_fitIconSizeDiff(int LR_fitIconSizeDiff) {
    this.LR_fitIconSizeDiff = LR_fitIconSizeDiff;
}

public Color getLR_backgroundHover() {
    return LR_backgroundHover;
}

public void setLR_backgroundHover(Color LR_backgroundHover) {
    this.LR_backgroundHover = LR_backgroundHover;
}

public Color getLR_background() {
    return LR_background;
}

public void setLR_background(Color LR_background) {
    setBackground(LR_background);
    this.LR_background = LR_background;
}

public boolean isLR_hoverEffect() {
    return LR_hoverEffect;
}

public void setLR_hoverEffect(boolean LR_hoverEffect) {
    this.LR_hoverEffect = LR_hoverEffect;
}
}
```

> Left button: LabelButton_Round.java

```
package com.sm.component;
import com.sm.easings.EasingsFunctions;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.Animator;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTarget;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.TimingTargetAdapter;
import org.jdesktop.animation.timing.interpolation.Interpolator;

public class LabelButton_Round extends JLabel {

private int LBR_arcValue = 10;
private boolean LBR_hoverEffect = false;
private Color LBR_background = new Color(255, 255, 255);
private Color LBR_backgroundHover = new Color(255, 255, 255);

// Animation
Animator animatorInBackground;
Animator animatorOutBackground;

public LabelButton_Round() {
    super.setOpaque(false);
    super.setFocusable(false);
    super.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
    initAnimations();
    initEvents();
}

private void initEvents() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            if (LBR_hoverEffect) {
                if (animatorInBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorInBackground.stop();
                }
                if (animatorOutBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorOutBackground.stop();
                }
                animatorInBackground.start();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            if (LBR_hoverEffect) {
                if (animatorInBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorInBackground.stop();
                }
                if (animatorOutBackground.isRunning()) {
                    animatorOutBackground.stop();
                }
                animatorOutBackground.start();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initAnimations() {
    
    TimingTarget targetBackground = new TimingTargetAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void timingEvent(float fraction) {
            if (animatorInBackground.isRunning()) {
                int rgbColor1 [] = new int [] {getBackground().getRed(), getBackground().getGreen(), getBackground().getBlue()};
                int rgbColor2 [] = new int [] {getLBR_backgroundHover().getRed(), getLBR_backgroundHover().getGreen(), getLBR_backgroundHover().getBlue()};
                int rgbFinal [] = new int [3];
                boolean factorCalculos [] = new boolean [3]; // True = Resta - False = Suma
                for (int i = 0; i < rgbFinal.length; i++) {
                    if (rgbColor1 [i] > rgbColor2 [i]) {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] - ((rgbColor1 [i] - rgbColor2 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = true;
                    } else {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] + ((rgbColor2 [i] - rgbColor1 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = false;
                    }
                }
                Color finalColor = new Color(rgbFinal [0], rgbFinal [1], rgbFinal [2]);
                setBackground(finalColor);
                if (getLBR_backgroundHover().equals(finalColor)) {
                    animatorInBackground.stop();
                }
            } else if (animatorOutBackground.isRunning()) {
                int rgbColor1 [] = new int [] {getBackground().getRed(), getBackground().getGreen(), getBackground().getBlue()};
                int rgbColor2 [] = new int [] {getLBR_background().getRed(), getLBR_background().getGreen(), getLBR_background().getBlue()};
                int rgbFinal [] = new int [3];
                boolean factorCalculos [] = new boolean [3]; // True = Resta - False = Suma
                for (int i = 0; i < rgbFinal.length; i++) {
                    if (rgbColor1 [i] > rgbColor2 [i]) {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] - ((rgbColor1 [i] - rgbColor2 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = true;
                    } else {
                        rgbFinal [i] = (int) (rgbColor1 [i] + ((rgbColor2 [i] - rgbColor1 [i]) * fraction));
                        factorCalculos [i] = false;
                    }
                }
                Color finalColor = new Color(rgbFinal [0], rgbFinal [1], rgbFinal [2]);
                setBackground(finalColor);
                if (getLBR_background().equals(finalColor)) {
                    animatorOutBackground.stop();
                }
            }
            repaint();
        }
    };
    animatorInBackground = new Animator(500, targetBackground);
    animatorInBackground.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
        @Override
        public float interpolate(float f) {
            return EasingsFunctions.easeInOutSine(f);
        }
    });
    animatorOutBackground = new Animator(500, targetBackground);
    animatorOutBackground.setInterpolator(new Interpolator() {
        @Override
        public float interpolate(float f) {
            return EasingsFunctions.easeInOutSine(f);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    
    g2d.setColor(getBackground().darker());
    g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), LBR_arcValue, LBR_arcValue);
    
    g2d.setColor(getBackground());
    g2d.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() - 5, LBR_arcValue, LBR_arcValue);
}

// Para no dejar que el usuario diseñe el botón
@Override
public void setBackground(Color bg) {
    super.setBackground(bg);
}

@Override
public Color getBackground() {
    return super.getBackground();
}

@Override
public void setCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    super.setCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void setOpaque(boolean isOpaque) {
    super.setOpaque(false);
}

@Override
public void setFocusable(boolean focusable) {
    super.setFocusable(false);
}

@Override
public void setHorizontalTextPosition(int textPosition) {
    super.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment) {
    super.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setVerticalAlignment(int alignment) {
    super.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setVerticalTextPosition(int textPosition) {
    super.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void setBorder(Border border) {
    super.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
}

public Color getLBR_backgroundHover() {
    return LBR_backgroundHover;
}

public void setLBR_backgroundHover(Color LBR_backgroundHover) {
    this.LBR_backgroundHover = LBR_backgroundHover;
}

public Color getLBR_background() {
    return LBR_background;
}

public void setLBR_background(Color LBR_background) {
    setBackground(LBR_background);
    this.LBR_background = LBR_background;
}

public boolean isLBR_hoverEffect() {
    return LBR_hoverEffect;
}

public void setLBR_hoverEffect(boolean LBR_hoverEffect) {
    this.LBR_hoverEffect = LBR_hoverEffect;
}

public int getLBR_arcValue() {
    return LBR_arcValue;
}

public void setLBR_arcValue(int LBR_arcValue) {
    this.LBR_arcValue = LBR_arcValue;
}
}
```

> Easings:

```
package com.sm.easings;

public interface Easings {
    public float easing(float f);
}
```

> EasingsFunctions:

```
package com.sm.easings;

public class EasingsFunctions {

public static float easeOutBounce(float x) {
    float n1 = 7.5625f;
    float d1 = 2.75f;
    double v;
    if (x < 1 / d1) {
        v = n1 * x * x;
    } else if (x < 2 / d1) {
        v = n1 * (x -= 1.5 / d1) * x + 0.75;
    } else if (x < 2.5 / d1) {
        v = n1 * (x -= 2.25 / d1) * x + 0.9375;
    } else {
        v = n1 * (x -= 2.625 / d1) * x + 0.984375;
    }
    return (float) v;
}

public static float easeOutQuint(float x) {
    return (float) (1 - Math.pow(1 - x, 5));
}

public static float easeOutSine(float x) {
    return (float) (Math.sin((x * Math.PI) / 2));
}

public static float easeInOutSine(float x) {
    return (float) (-(Math.cos(Math.PI * x) - 1) / 2);
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the issue is and the code uses 3rd party classes so I can't test. Maybe this will give you some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31764608/basicbuttonui-button-won-t-repaint/31764665#31764665. It uses a different approach in that the logic is isolated in a single class so it can be used with any component as oppose to your approach which duplicates the hover logic. The example uses a FocusListener but you can easily use a MouseListener. just map the focusGained/Lost logic to the mouseEntered/Exited logic.

Comment: Hey yo, thanks for that, bud, gonna use it.