# can i add a CSS file to JFrame?

Tags: java, css, swing, jframe

I want to add a well-designed button in my `JFrame` I created a button using `JButton` now I want to design it using CSS file and want to change color and add border etc. let me know if its possible or not?

Comment: Use JavaFX or write your own Look and Feel Delegate

Comment: I think you don't need to add css file. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698092/design-button-in-java-like-in-css) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

swing not supported css

To add border:

```
jButton1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 0, 1, new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
```

To change background:

```
jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 204, 0));
```

And read more about JButton

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html